# Factoring polynomials again

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

$bc(b+c)+ac(c+a)-ab(a+b)$

---

*Edit by @Andreas: This should be:*

$bc(b+c)+ac(c-a)-ab(a+b)$

---

Answer: $(a+b)(c-a)(b+c)$

I did: 
$b^{2}c+bc^{2}+ac^{2}+a^{2}c-a^{2}b-ab^{2}$ 
After this step I can't find a way to continue, could you give me a light on this solution?

Comment: You multiply out the answer and show it's the same.

Comment: @Gaffney no, it's not a prof, I must factor out this polynomial

Comment: Expand the "answer", you will see that it is not correct.

Comment: @CYAries maybe the book wrote wrong them?

Comment: If the answer is correct, $bc(b+c)+ac(c+a)$ must be divisible by $a+b$, but it is not.

Comment: @NicolasLeskiu  Factoring is just expanding backwards...

Comment: @Gaffney I know this, but I must do the factorization without knowing the answer previously. I put the answer there 'cause I wasn't able to solve.

Comment: Mathematica cannot factor this expression either. Are you sure you copied the expression correctly?

Comment: @celtschk Absolutely

Comment: I've verified it tons of times

Comment: I put an edit in the OP's question to make it correct.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, I guess the author of my book made a mistake there  when he was typing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed as follows (add and subtract the red b, then regroup):

$$
bc(b+c)+ac(c-a)-ab(a+b)\\
= bc(b+c)+ac(\color{red}b+c-(a+\color{red}b))-ab(a+b)\\
= (bc+ac)(b+c)- (ac+ab)(a+b)\\
= c(a+b)(b+c)- a(b+c)(a+b)\\
= (c-a)(a+b)(b+c)
$$

Comment: The identity (with $b$ replaced by $-b$) is symmetric in $a,b,c$ and appears in several contexts. See id3_4_1_3a in [Special Algebraic Identities](http://somos.crg4.com/ident04.gp).

Comment: Mr. Andreas, but how have you found that adding and subtracting $b$ would come to the answer?  Cause I would never come to find such idea in my whole life. Thanks by the way.

Comment: A bit of guessing, a bit of logic. The latter: you don't want to destroy brackets, but regroup them. So you won't expand the expression into elementary products, but keep brackets. As $(a+b)$ and $(b+c)$ are already there, the guess is to transform $(c-a)$  into a linear combination of these two, and - alas! - adding and subtracting $b$ does it. The rest is then stoical, it may as well not have worked out.